# Complexity and algorithms of functions

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, complexity-theory

I've seen many people asking for complexity of their own algorithms but is it possible to see the time/space complexity of all the functions (e.g string.indexof etc) in C# ? and if possible we could see the algorithm they implement???

if its possible, where can we find??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most built in functions are of what ever is the standard best case solutions to a problem. If you want any more information you may be able to find it on msdn.com.
Otherwise you won't be able to see the microsoft code with out working there.

Comment: i believe someone quoted the idea of reflection (why did he remove that :( )... that was a nice idea to look into MS code...

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the latest MSDN documentation includes method complexity for collection types.

Comment: Look in remarks section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx `List<T>.IndexOf()`

Comment: agreed, that's quite nice...but would have loved to see string.IndexOf(String).